# Getting DDL Before Updating the Schema in Hibernate Spring Applications

Tags: spring, hibernate, oracle10g

In a Spring-Hibernate application, `hibernate.show_sql=true` in **log4j** property file is enough to show to hibernate generated query. But what we have to do if we need the actual sql query.(For production environment i need to observer and verify the query before updating the schema).

What i am going to do is, after the first schema generation in production( by hibernate itself) i dont want hibernate to update the schema(DDL).I want to hijack the alter, update (DDL) queries and after verification i would like to run those scripts manually in DB. 
Is there any approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has build-in a function to enable the logging of all the generated SQL statements to the console. You can enable it by add a `show_sql` property in the Hibernate configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml`. This function is good for basic troubleshooting, and to see what’s Hibernate is doing behind.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

**show_sql**

Enable the logging of all the generated SQL statements to the console

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

**format_sql**

Format the generated SQL statement to make it more readable, but takes up more screen space.

```
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

**use_sql_comments**

Hibernate will put comments inside all generated SQL statements to hint what’s the generated SQL trying to do

```
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG ## is equivalent to hibernate.show_sql=true
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE ## allows you to see the binding parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug

log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hb.layout.ConversionPattern=HibernateLog --> %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.hb.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug
```

To print the bind parameters as well, add the following to your log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.net.sf.hibernate.type=debug
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configurations in **log4j.properties** file

logs the SQL statements
`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug`

Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace`

Enable the show sql property in hibernate configuration file as follows.

`<property name="show_sql">true</property>`

For more details, check the [post](http://supportmycode.com/2014/08/20/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values/)