# Hibernate - how to persist Map<UUID,POJO>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i cant find what is wrong with my annotations (i have used official hibernate documentation)

```
public class DashletContainer{

private Map<UUID, DashletData> dashletData = new HashMap<>();
//STUFF

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "rd_container_data")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "dashletdata_dashlet_id")
    public Map<UUID, DashletData> getDashletData() {
        return dashletData;
    }
}


public class DashletData{

//STUFF

    @Column(name = "dashlet_id")
    public UUID getDashletId() {
        return dashletId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public DashletContainer getDashletContainer() {
        return dashletContainer;
    }
}
```

and this is the structure of my join table(rd_container_data) on database :

```
dashletdata_id      | UUID
dashletcontainer_id | UUID
dashletdata_dashlet_id  | UUID
```

the problem is when i persist the container object the Map inside it stays Null and nothing get inserted inside corresponding table.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

@dave try adding `@MapKeyColumn(name = "dashletdata_dashlet_id")` on the property `dashletData` instead on `getter`

Comment: i did that and : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column dashletdat0_.dashletdata_key does not exist . now i am trying to solve this error

Comment: @dave hmm... just before persisting , data is there..?? have you seen the generated SQL, is there any inserted statement fired for this table

Comment: yes. before insertion data is there. how can i see generated SQL?

Comment: i changed my strategy to an older technique (the one without join table)     @OneToMany(mappedBy="dashletContainer")
    @MapKey(name="dashletId")

Comment: @dave see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473551/getting-ddl-before-updating-the-schema-in-hibernate-spring-applications/25473754#25473754) for turning SQL on

Comment: my tables were extending a base_table , there were fields in base_table that could not be null.

Comment: @dave, how can a table extend another table in SQL? add some code to understand your scenario with details on what is the issue you are facing now

Comment: @user2065083 inheritance is so possible in PostgreSQL. columns of a super table will be inherited by sub table. i solved the issue by eliminating extending of the super class.